# Java tree reference always null

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I have a problem with the raiz parameter in the methods insertar and preorden, inorden and postorden, the reference that I pass in the main method never change and it's like the three doesn't have any element I think. So when I try to run the method preorden it's like the tree is empty and it doesn't print anything.

PD: I'm inserting numbers to a binary search tree and I have to order them in preorder, inorder and postorder.

```
public class ABBNodo {
    int data;
    ABBNodo izq;
    ABBNodo der;

    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(int data){
        this.data=data;
    }

    public ABBNodo getIzq(){
        return izq;
    }

    public void setIzq(ABBNodo izq){
        this.izq=izq;
    }

    public ABBNodo getDer(){
        return der;
    }

    public void setDer(ABBNodo der){
        this.der=der;
    }


}


class ABB{
    ABBNodo raiz;
    ABBNodo buscar(ABBNodo raiz, int data){
        if(raiz== null) return null;
        if(data<raiz.getData()) return buscar(raiz.getIzq(),data);
        else if(data>raiz.getData()) return buscar(raiz.getDer(),data);
        return raiz;
    }

    ABBNodo insertar(ABBNodo raiz, int data){
        if(raiz==null){
            raiz=new ABBNodo();
            if(raiz==null){
                System.out.println("Error de memoria"); return raiz;
            }else{
                raiz.setData(data);
                raiz.setIzq(null); raiz.setDer(null);
            }   
            }else{
                if(data<raiz.getData()) raiz.setIzq(insertar(raiz.getIzq(),data));
                else if(data>raiz.getData()) raiz.setDer(insertar(raiz.getDer(),data));
        }
        return raiz;
    }

    void preOrden(ABBNodo raiz){
        if(raiz!=null){
            System.out.println(raiz.getData());
            preOrden(raiz.getIzq());
            preOrden(raiz.getDer());
        }
    }

    void inOrden(ABBNodo raiz){
        if(raiz!=null){
            inOrden(raiz.getIzq());
            System.out.println(raiz.getData());
            inOrden(raiz.getDer());
        }
    }

    void postOrden(ABBNodo raiz){
        if(raiz!=null){
            postOrden(raiz.getIzq());
            postOrden(raiz.getDer());
            System.out.println(raiz.getData());
        }
    }
}

class main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ABB a1=new ABB();
        int data=0;
        ABBNodo raiz = null; //This never changes
        do{
        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero que quiere agregar al arbol");
        data=Lectura.readInt();
        a1.insertar(raiz, data);
        }while(data!=-1);
        a1.inOrden(raiz);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you ever assign anything to `this.raiz`?? It looks to never be assigned an instance and so should remain null.

Comment: Where should I do that? I copied and tried to understand the methods from a book but I'm having problems with raiz.

Answer (score 0):

You never set raiz to null so the first if condition in insertar will never be met which means you'll never end up having a root for your tree. Create a constructor  for your ABB class that sets raiz to null so that when you create an instance of the ABB class it will be set to null and then your insertar method will be able to create a root node.